# In mac os, use rxtx with an error of java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, classpath, rxtx

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
    at healthyMouse.SerialPortTest.initialize(SerialPortTest.java:27)
    at healthyMouse.SerialPortTest.main(SerialPortTest.java:81)
```

I'm using MAC OS 10.7.5 and Eclipse. I use buildPath->configure build path->add external jars to import the RXTXcomm.jar. And I get the error. I'm new with MAC OS, so I'm a little confused how to import libraries for eclipse java in MAC. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a suggestion due I don't use Mac OS but I've worked with RXTX on Windows and it´s necessary copy `rxtxSerial.dll`into the project folder to make it work. Try copying `librxtxSerial.jnilib` into your project folder and maybe you have luck.